# Open Popup in Second Monitor using ASP MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, popup

I've done a lot of research and am able to accomplish opening up a "form" or a "popup" in a second monitor. This is assuming that the user has a two monitor setup on their desktop.

The catch here is that I can only do it in a webforms application. I can set the StartPosition of the form that will be my popup to be Manual, and then setting the location through the Screen.AllScreens properties when it gets triggered in the parent form using a button. I am experimenting with providing the same kind of functionality but in an MVC app instead.

At this point, I am making a simple javascript call in my cshtml view to my controller to return a partial view and then displaying it in a new window as follows:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var myWin = window.open('/HomeController/ActionThatGetsMyPartialView',"_blank");
</script>
```

And my HomeController has the method:

```
    public PartialViewResult ActionThatGetsMyPartialView()
    {
        return PartialView("MyPartialView");
    }
```

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how I can control the location of the window that will be popping up. I know I can set the location of a window using javascripts Screen object, but this "Screen" object is I guess is not the same as the WinForms "Screen" object which gives me access to the monitors that the user has setup on their computer.

I don't know if this is a trivial thing, but my googlefu was not good enough to find anything that was targetting toward an MVC solution! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MVC is a server framework, you need a client side solution. Try searching around for Javascript methods or libraries to position browser windows.

Comment: Yah, I guess I was wondering if there was any other way similar to the WebForms method I had created. I can just set the "top" and/or "left" attributes of my window when I open it in javascript. Thanks for the advice!